# Eliminating Null Productions from Context Free Grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Here is a problem I am trying to solve:

```
S -> 0A0 | 1B1 | BB
A -> C
B -> S | A
C -> S | e
```

I know that C is nullable (since it produces an epsilon) and A is nullable (since it produces C, which is nullable). My question is if B is nullable too since it produces A which produces C which are both nullable?

Comment: What have you tried?  What research and self-study have you done?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research/self-study before asking, and to show us in the question what you've tried.  This should be covered by definitions and algorithms presented in standard textbooks on automata theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  We have the derivation $B \to A \to C \to \epsilon$, so $B$ is nullable.